# When fading out with GSAP, then fading back in with a rotationY, the animated element's back is not visible until animation is finished

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm using the library GSAP to animate some elements.
There seems to be a bug when fading an element out using opacity:0, or autoAlpha:0, then fading them back in with the same properties plus a rotationY: 180.

The element rotates, but only it's front is visible, when the animation completes, the backside pops in replacing the front.

When not using autoAlpha the element's sides are showing as expected.

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peuhafLm/8/) to illustrate the problem

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
if (event.charCode === 97) {

    let tl = gsap.timeline({});

    tl.to('.a', {
        x: -100, 
        duration: 3, 
        autoAlpha:0 ,
        rotationY: 0, 
        ease: 'power4.out'
    }, 0);

    tl.to('.c', {
        x: 100, 
        duration: 3, 
        rotationY: 0, 
        ease: 'power4.out'
    }, 0);


}
if (event.charCode === 106) {

    let tl = gsap.timeline({});

    tl.to('.a', {
        x: 0, 
        duration: 3, 
        autoAlpha:1, 
        rotationY: 180 , 
        ease: 'power4.out'
    }, 0);

    tl.to('.c', {
        x: 0, 
        duration: 3, 
        rotationY: 180 , 
        ease: 'power4.out'
    }, 0);

}
});
```

Any ideas why is this happening and how to solve it?